# Where to put Expanded inside Form Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have this login form and when I press the second RaisedButton the keyboard comes up and the yellow/black banner of the problem in display widgets appears.

I want to know where exactly shall I put Expanded widget in this code to avoid this error:

```
body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          RaisedButton(),
          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
          Text(''),
          RaisedButton(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your root `Scaffold`. @Alex Ali

Comment: Thank you @T.TSage ... It is really much easier than using Expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your root `Scaffold`.

Example below:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    );
```